# facebook notification from website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i want to send a notification to user from my website, i just done login with facebook and now i can see facebook friend list, post and so on. i have also user code and information from fb, and i just registered a facebook app to do this. i take with this method

```
    $queries = array(
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/home?limit=50'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
    array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/photos?limit=6'),
);
```

how i can send a notification to a user now?

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839090/send-notification-to-user-from-app-via-notification-api

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/09/28/facebook-api-app-notifications-api-for-facebook-canvas-apps/) covers how to make an API call to send Notifications to users.

However, it's worth noting that notifications are only allowed from Canvas Applications and not websites that use Facebook. The notifications are designed to link back to the Canvas URL of your application.