# Facebook SDK PHP: send notifications

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have an API that serves Android, IOS and Windows Phone apps. The API works fine with Facebook Graph API. I'm trying to create a method that sends a Facebook notification to user, based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839090/send-notification-to-user-from-app-via-notification-api) and [Facebook SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications). Here is my code:

```
public function sendNotification($uid, $msg, $link){    

    $postdata = "access_token=$this->access_token&href=$link&template=$msg";        
    $opts = ['http' => ['method'  => 'POST', 'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'content' => $postdata]];
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$uid/notifications";
    $r = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    var_dump( $r );
    die();
}
```

My `Facebook` class has `uid`, `access_token`, `app_id` and `app_secret` attributes. I should call:

```
$fb = new Facebook();
$fb->sendNotification($uid, 'Test message', 'http://test.com');
```

I have the following `var_dump`:

```
<b>Warning</b>:
file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/100001795849314/notifications): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\faceteen\api\Classes\Facebook.php</b> on line <b>144</b><br />
bool(false)
```

I'm running on `localhost` with Facebook Graph generated token (with `manage_notifications` perm). I don't want to use Facebook's class, but my own. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _“What am I doing wrong?”_ – this: _“I don't want to use Facebook's class, but my own.”_

Comment: I solved this using Facebook's class. Thanks.

Comment: can you put an example ?