# iOS: Detect app start via notification press

Tags: ios

is there a way to detect if my App is started from a notification being displayed on the home screen?

When my App is going into background I schedule a UILocalNotification. When the user presses this notification at the home screen, the app is starting again. I want to get this information that my app was started again from pressing the notification.

I already tried out what was mentioned in [Send notification to user from app via notification API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839090/send-notification-to-user-from-app-via-notification-api) but the app does not call the method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate method you are implementing is for remote notifications. In order to get the user info for the local notifications scheduled by your app you have to implement:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveLocalNotification:) has all the information you need on local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function in your app delegate

```
       NSDictionary *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (localNotif)
{
//your code here

}
```