# How to detect if an app was opened by a notification action in the ViewController

Tags: swift, swift3

I am working on a notification app and was wondering if it is possible to detect if the app is opened from a notification action in ViewController.Swift instead of the AppDelegate.swift. How can I do this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059352/ios-detect-app-start-via-notification-press) seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Krish, Whenever the app is launched the `AppDelegate` gets called(if the default `Main` class is not modified) and in the AppDelegate class you can check for the launch option in launch option delegate whether its opened through remote notification. This is the first action where you will catch the app opening event.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let remoteNotif = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary

    if remoteNotif != nil {
        let notifName = remoteNotif?["aps"] as! String
        print("Notification: \(notifName )")
    }
    else {
        print("Not remote")
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason when I ran it and used a remote notification nothing was printed back to the console

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a complete and easy answer to that](http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/)

After you handle the event on AppDelegate you can use an observer to let your ViewController of that event. 
Normally you should redirect the user to a specific view, depending on the notification payload.