# How to securely get & use Facebook App Access Token to send Notifications using PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get my head around the correct way to securely get an app access token and how to use it to send notifications to users of my app.

From reading Facebook's docs, and other questions on here, I think the app token should only be generated server-side, so I'm trying to include the Graph API call to get the token, inside a php script, instead of having it in my client-side Javascript code. This is the php script I've written to achieve this:

getapptoken.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "MYSERVERNAME";
$username = "MYUSERNAME";
$password = "MYPASSWORD";
$dbname = "MYDBNAME";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    GET /oauth/access_token?
        client_id={MYAPPID}
        &amp;client_secret={MYAPPSECRET}
</script>
"
    }

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

I have my App ID and App Secret contained in this php file, I'm then trying to make a call to the Graph API to get my App access token, and then I'm trying to echo the response (the access token) back to my Javascript file/function (which is client-side), so that it can be used to send notifications below:

```
 function deliverNotifications(){

    // Using AJAX to get the apptoken as the response from getapptoken.php
    // This response is then stored in the variable named "apptoken"
    $.ajax({
            url: 'scripts/getapptoken.php',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){
                if (response.error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + response.error.message);
                }
                else {

                var apptoken = response;

    //Defining the Array of IDs to send notifications to
    var myArray = [45563562722445, 83724562462, 245622722725, 367345634562];

    //Iterating through each ID and sending a notification to each one
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 

        FB.api( 
       "/"+myArray[i]+"/notifications",
        "POST",
       {
            "template": "This is a test notification!",
// Trying to use the variable named "apptoken" here to include the required app token
            "access_token": ""+apptoken+""
        },
        function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error) {
              console.log("notification should be sent.");
          } else {
          console.log(response);
             }
          }
         );             
        }}
```

Unfortunately this isn't working, I'm not even sure if this is a secure method to use, since I'm storing the access token inside a variable on the client-side.

I would really appreciate anyone's help or advice on the correct way to do this. Is my code completely incorrect? Or does it only require some small changes?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to "get an App Access Token", the App Token is just a combination of App ID and App Secret:

```
$app_token = APPID . '|' . APPSECRET;
```

Just use that one server side only, of course. Do not send the App Token to the client! You can either use the PHP SDK to use the notifications endpoint, or you can use cURL on your own.

Comment: Hi @luschn thanks for your reply! That sounds much easier, do you mean I can just define the app token inside the php, for example like ``$app_token = 3642643632 . '|' . db4j8d38j3dbff37;``, but I shouldn't echo ``$app_token`` back to the Javascript file that the client can see? I'm a little confused as to how I can use the token in the code which sends notifications without first sending it back to that code from the php file. Do you mean I should POST the array of IDs to the php file and try to send notifications from inside there instead of doing it in a Javascript file?

Comment: is the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839090/send-notification-to-user-from-app-via-notification-api the correct method to use to ensure that the App Token remains secure? Would the code in that answer be correct, and I would just need to ensure that ``RECEIVER_USER_ID`` is where the IDs in my array go? Thanks again.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, the app token is secure as long as you only use it server side. and yes, the code in the accepted answer is correct. although it is using a very old php sdk. i would rather just use php curl without the php sdk, if it´s only for sending notifications.

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't sure if the php file might be visible to the client, if not then that's okay. I've never used php curl before and it looks a bit daunting, the php sdk code makes more sense to me, is it very out of date? I looked at the newest version (v5) but I wasn't able to find any examples of code for sending notifications to see if there's a lot of difference between the latest version and the code in the above answer, do you think there would be any issues using that older code? Thanks again.

Comment: curl is just a few lines of code, no big deal. for example: http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: the php sdk in that other answer is very outdated, yes. it will most likely work, but i would rather use the latest one of your own code. again, there is no need for any sdk if you just want to send notifications. just do some testing and some research, there is a lot of information about curl.